# Curl to podman service over IPv6

Tags: networking, ipv6, podman

I have CentOS8 VM with podman. I start my container as below

> ```
> podman run --name mycontainer --rm -h host6 -p [::]:443:443 -v /root/data:/data:Z 13ac5a89eb93
> ```

This shows that the service is listening on port 443

O/P of podman ps -a.

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                          COMMAND     CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS            NAMES
c8aef6cb1233  localhost/prod:2.1.0              About a minute ago  Up About a minute ago  :::443->443/tcp  mycontainer
```

O/P of lsof -Pnl +M -i | grep 443

```
conmon    1499659        0    5u  IPv6 92925840      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

From the output we can see conmon is listening on port 443 but I am not able to curl command to connect.

```
curl -k -v https://host6/
*   Trying 2400::132...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 2400::132 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to amshost6 port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to host6 port 443: Connection refused
```

What could be the reason of connection getting refused?